# Google Cloud Endpoints: NumberFormatException in Android client when response includes DateTime field

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-api-java-client, google-cloud-endpoints, google-api-client

I'm just starting with Google Cloud Endpoints, 
I built an API in Python and even got to use the generated sources in the Android Studio/Gradle environment.

I'm facing a problem that whenever the response from Cloud Endpoints includes a DateTime object, a NumberFormatException is thrown.

```
08-05 13:27:28.143  32116-32141/com.dgt.ds E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
        java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
        Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:  [key created_at, field private com.google.api.client.util.DateTime com.google.api.services.dsApi.model.ServicesDResponse.createdAt]
        at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:797)
        at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:438)
        at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:745)
        at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:358)
        at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parse(JsonParser.java:331)
        at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:87)
        at com.google.api.client.json.JsonObjectParser.parseAndClose(JsonObjectParser.java:81)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse.parseAs(HttpResponse.java:459)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:460)
        at com.dgt.ds.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:70)
        at com.dgt.ds.MainActivity$1.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:58)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
        ... 5 more
        Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid date/time format: 2013-08-05T10:27:27.449810
        at com.google.api.client.util.DateTime.parseRfc3339(DateTime.java:301)
        at com.google.api.client.util.Data.parsePrimitiveValue(Data.java:435)
        at com.google.api.client.json.JsonParser.parseValue(JsonParser.java:795)
        ... 17 more
```

this is the message object in Python (I'm using `message_types.DateTimeField`):

```
class DResponse(messages.Message):
    id = messages.StringField(1)
    created_at = message_types.DateTimeField(2)
    author = messages.StringField(3)
    description = messages.StringField(4, required=True)
```

how can I fix this ?

Comment: It may be a bug in either the way `DateTimeField` is implemented or in the Java client library. What does the JSON payload look like for the same request? You can test it out by visiting the APIs explorer for your app at `https://yourappid.appspot.com/_ah/api/explorer`.

Comment: @bossylobster it looks like a proper JSON response, the DateTimeField is `"created_at": "2013-08-05T10:27:27.449000"`

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some more digging.

Comment: The issue is that the Python stamp has 6 digits after the decimal and the Java library expects exactly 3. This seems to be a bug, but I'm not sure where.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused by the fact that `protorpc.protojson.ProtoJson.encode_field` is [using](https://code.google.com/p/google-protorpc/source/browse/python/protorpc/protojson.py?r=a3273cbed70bd9de4a22a923ee78e6fec8fe2cbc#162) `isoformat` on native `datetime.datetime` objects.

This uses microseconds instead of milliseconds (since the `datetime` module in Python uses microseconds) and as a result, this fails the Java client library parser.

For a short term fix you could do one of two things:

- Stop using `DateTimeField` and just use an `IntegerField`, relying on your clients to send timestamps as integers
- Monkey patch `protorpc/protojson.py` to reference a subclass of `ProtoJson` which behaves correctly. Essentially, `isoformat()` shouldn't be used and you should use a hybrid which only has 3 places after the decimal.

Comment: I kinda searched everywhere to find a solution to this, couldn't find any other than what you suggested. Using `datetime.replace(microsecond=0)` failed as well.

Comment: `protorpc/protojson.py` should be fixed by now? I don't think a patch is necessary.

Comment: I still have the error with the current SDK I think

Comment: The SDK doesn't influence the server side error. I'm sorry I no longer work at Google so can't help much beyond my original answer.

Comment: It's not server side i think. It's on the android-java end of the whole endpoints framework.

Comment: The issue with the SDK is that the server is serializing the data the wrong way.